# Is Chrome supposed to ignore the unsafe-inline directive if a hash is declared?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, security, content-security-policy

Given the following:

```
"Content-Security-Policy" value="
     default-src 'none'; 
     script-src 'unsafe-eval' 'unsafe-inline' 'self' *.myhost.com 'sha256-myHash';

<script type="text/javascript" src="myScript.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" integrity='sha-256-myHash'>
     //some stuff
</script>
```

I expect the bottom script to not load unless a hash is provided. I was under the impression Chrome would ignore unsafe-inline and look for a hash. Unsafe-inline simply being a fallback for IE.

Another method I tried was this:

(as discussed [here](https://websec.be/blog/cspstrictdynamic/#top-of-page))

```
"Content-Security-Policy" value="
             default-src 'self'
             script-src 'self' 'unsafe-inline' 'strict-dynamic' *.myhost.com http: https:;

@Scripts.Render("~/bundles/myScripts");
```

This never loads my local scripts, it ignores white listing due to strict-dynamic, thus anything MVC is spitting out via Scripts.Render won't load.

I understand an inline script isn't ideal, but it cannot be avoided right now. I am 99% certain there is a SO post somewhere that discusses this, wherein it's detailed what is optimal for cross browser support (i.e. Chrome ignoring unsafe-inline but having it present for IE) but I cannot find the thing to save my life.

Any pointers?

Thanks.

Comment: `unsafe-inline` means that it's okay to run any inline scripts without needing a hash. Why are you surprised that when you set it, that you can run inline scripts without a hash?

Comment: "Let’s break it down case by case. The best case scenario is when the user has a browser that supports strict-dynamic. In that case, the following rules apply:

Using nonces means that the browser will ignore unsafe-inline, so inline scripts are blocked" As per https://websec.be/blog/cspstrictdynamic/#top-of-page.

Comment: But in the case where the inline script ran, that doesn't apply, because you weren't using strict-dynamic that time.

Comment: I must be getting my wires crossed somewhere. As said, I thought Chrome would ignore unsafe-inline if a hash is provided / integrity is set to a value.

Comment: Why do you think that? Where is it documented to work anywhere like that?

Comment: @JosephSible - it would appear modern browsers do ignore unsafe-inline if a nonce is set, but not a hash. I remembered it as a hash value, thus the confusion.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's actually a nonce that will be used if present, not a hash.

Some further information can be found here:

https://csp.withgoogle.com/docs/strict-csp.html